# How to construct object to serialize like elements under the same parent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I place  collection of same elemets under parent element  when serialezed:

Serialization produces the following:

```
<Vehicle>
    <Type color="red" speed="50mph">Ford</Type>
</Vehicle>

<Vehicle>
    <Type color="blue" speed="70mph">Toyota</Type>
</Vehicle>
```

Instead of:

```
<Vehicle>
    <Type color="red" speed="50mph">Ford</Type>
    <Type color="blue" speed="70mph">Toyota</Type>
</Vehicle>

Here is my model:

[Serializable]
 [XmlRoot("Vehicle")]
public class Production
{
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Vehicle
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string color { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string speed { get; set; }
}
```

I serialize using:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Prodcution));
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Vehicles.xml");
writer.Serialize(file, Vehicle);
file.Close();
```

I tried something like this which generated errors:

```
[XmlArray("Vehicle")]
ArrayItem("Vehicles")]
public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this? What you are trying to do basically means 1 vehicle can have two types at the same time. Assuming you have this XML, how would the deserialized object look like in this case?

Comment: I am sending the XML to a third party application and it parses the data this way

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that you want

```
<Vehicles>
    <Vehicle>
        <Type color="red" speed="50mph">Ford</Type>
    </Vehicle>

    <Vehicle>
        <Type color="blue" speed="70mph">Toyota</Type>
    </Vehicle>
</Vehicles>
```

you almost have it [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx)

```
[XmlArray("Vehicles")]
public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
```